# How to sort $_FILES by number indexes first?

Tags: php, file, sorting

When multiple files are uploaded, PHP sorts the files like this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => game-of-thrones-series-1080p-hd-wallpaper-movies.jpg
            [1] => HD-Hitman-Wallpaper.jpg
            [2] => New-Games-Wallpapers-Full-HD-1080p.jpg
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/jpeg
            [1] => image/jpeg
            [2] => image/jpeg
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php7659.tmp
            [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\php765A.tmp
            [2] => C:\xampp\tmp\php766A.tmp
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 579476
            [1] => 1006801
            [2] => 532174
        )
)
```

I want to sort the files by the file number first, like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => game-of-thrones-series-1080p-hd-wallpaper-movies.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php7659.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 579476
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => HD-Hitman-Wallpaper.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php765A.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1006801
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => New-Games-Wallpapers-Full-HD-1080p.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php766A.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 532174
        )
)
```

I know it can be done by using a foreach loop but I'm looking for a more simplified and efficient way. Any idea how to do it otherwise?

Comment: I dont think there is any buddy, foreach is the way

Comment: "more efficient"? no. in order to *process every element*, you **have to** *touch every element* at least once. which is exactly what foreach is doing.